# How to parse BigInt in specific base?

Tags: javascript, bigint

For integer we have parseInt, which accepts base as an argument. For bases 2, 8, 10 and 16 we can use some prefix, but for others we forsed to use parseInt:

```js
console.log(parseInt("10", 2), +"0b10")
console.log(parseInt("10", 8), +"0o10")
console.log(parseInt("10", 10), +"10")
console.log(parseInt("10", 14))
console.log(parseInt("10", 16), +"0x10")
console.log(parseInt("10", 36))
```

Now I'm looking at `BigInt` and can't find there anything like that. How can I parse bigint in specific base without writing my own function?

```js
console.log("" + BigInt("0b10"))
console.log("" + BigInt("0o10"))
console.log("" + BigInt("10"))
console.log("" + "base 14?")
console.log("" + BigInt("0x10"))
console.log("" + "base 36?")
```

Comment: well done! Thanks.